# Different array sizes

Tags: c, sizeof

When I run the following program, I get different array sizes. I tired different ways but the result is the same, what could io be doing wrong ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void array_size(char *a[])
{
    printf("Func Array Size: %d\n", sizeof(a));
}

int main()
{
    char *str_array[]={"one", "two", "three"};

    printf("Array Size: %d\n", (int)sizeof(str_array));

    array_size(str_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sizeof(a) is  pointer size. not array size

Comment: From C99 you can use the `"%zu"` to correctly print a `size_t`value.

Answer (score 1):

In function main `str_array` is an array with three `char *`.

The parameter `a` of function array_size is just a pointer. The compiler does not dynamically pass array length information when calling array_size.

The size of one pointer is not equal the size of three `char *` pointers.

Answer (score -1):

This is because `sizeof` is a compiler built-in and not a runtime function. It is hard-coded into the binary.

```
`sizeof((char *)[]) = sizeof(a) = sizeof(void *)`
`sizeof(str_array) = sizeof({"one", "two", "three"}) = 3 * sizeof(char *)`
```

Comment: That's not the issue. Also, it's not guaranteed that `sizeof(char **) == `sizeof(void *)`.